# iOS WKWebview send post request by js, compose the request from current webpage's html

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

WKWebView has a bug that user's http body of post request coming from webview will be dropped.
so, I want to resend the post request by evaluating javascript.
I want to know if there is any way to get the form element  in function decidePolicyForNavigationAction?

My thought is that I can look the URL of request in decidePolicyForNavigationAction, if it is a post request, then I can use javascript to get the form and compose a post request with HTTPBody and send it out.
Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: yes it is possible. But can you tell more about the bug you assume to be in WKWebView? Best done with sharing some lines of code about your intentional design pattern

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/18952
This is the bug I met probably.